# Why don't these two summations provide the same result

Tags: summation, economics

Our business is trying to back into a price discount total based on forecasts of gross sales, percent of gross sales, and percent of MSRP.  The gross sales are forecasted by day while the percent of gross sales and percent of MSRP are forecasted by product status and month.  For example, I may forecast that 2.5% of total gross sales today will come from products in the "F" status, and those products will be sold at 53% of MSRP.

Here's a budget for percent of gross sales and percent of MSRP last month:

```
+----------+-------------+-----------+
|          | % of Demand | % of MSRP |
+----------+-------------+-----------+
| Status B | 2.49%       | 39.01%    |
+----------+-------------+-----------+
| Status I | 9.02%       | 53.48%    |
+----------+-------------+-----------+
| Status A | 19.58%      | 99.00%    |
+----------+-------------+-----------+
| Status T | 20.57%      | 99.00%    |
+----------+-------------+-----------+
| Status N | 32.31%      | 99.00%    |
+----------+-------------+-----------+
| Status S | 10.00%      | 82.49%    |
+----------+-------------+-----------+
| Status F | 7.03%       | 97.77%    |
+----------+-------------+-----------+
```

If I want to calculate the weighted MSRP, I use this formula:
$Weighted MSRP = \sum(Percent of Demand)(Percent of MSRP$)

For the table above I get 92.7%

However, when I include the sales forecast I get something different.  The formula I will use is this:
$Weighted MSRP = \frac{Gross Sales}{\sum\frac{(Percent of Demand)(Gross Sales)}{Percent of MSRP}}$

This formula makes sense to me because the main denominator should give me Gross MSRP dollars, and dividing Gross Sales by Gross MSRP dollars should give me the Percent of MSRP.
However, when I do the calculation it does not match my first.  For example, if I use a gross sales total of 44,115.40 with the table of data above I am seeing a Total MSRP Dollars of 52,504.59 and a Weighted MSRP of 84%, which is much different than the 92.7 I calculated above.  Why aren't these MSRP percentages matching?

Comment: Percentage of demand for a product is computed off of gross sales of all products combined. What does the gross sales in the denominator refer to?

Comment: @sku Multiply the Gross Sales by the Percent of Demand for each product status to get the Sales Sold by products in that status.  Divide that by MSRP to get the MSRP Dollars by products in that status.  Sum them together to get the MSRP Dollars across all item statuses.

Comment: Your first formula seems to be wrong. MSRP of each item is different. So using %age MSRP loses some information. Take some real numbers and you will figure it out.

Comment: @sku You're right, it is.  I wish to know what mathematical or economic principal can be used to demonstrate it is wrong.